# getting the file input value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i am building one module wherein user can post their data.
i have few text field and one image which while uploading via the HTML input control needs to previewed.

My Approach:

the HTML part:

```
    <div class="divClass" id="FirstAd">
<h4 align="center">
        Advertisement 1</h4>
    <div style="float: left; width:25%">
        <img src="images.jpg" id="replaceMe" width="100px" height="130px" /></div>
    <div style="float: right; width:70%; left:30%">
        <input type="text" style="width: 197px" /><br />
        <br />
        <textarea class="AdContent"></textarea><br />
        <br />
        <input type="file" id="myImage" size="30" onchange="pictureUpload()" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Preview!"/><br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

the j Query part:

```
      function pictureUpload() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var imagepath = "file:\\" + $("#myImage").val();
            $("#replaceMe").attr("src", imagepath);
            alert(imagepath);
        });
    }
```

Am able to just get the filename with the extension not the path.

is there any alternative?? 
or some jquery plugin?? 
or can we retrieve the path inside a hidden field, since it is a security measure to prevent retrieving path from the file input ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be done by this way 
there is post in stack overflow by

[by Ivan--thanks Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-before-upload-image)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this. The `input type="file"` has security around it so that you can't directly access the file from JavaScript.